# Removing underline partially from a link

Tags: html, css, text-decorations

I have the following 'link-box' in my footer:

[image]

This is the **HTML**:

```
<div id="link-box" style="height: 80px; width: 335px;">
    <a href="index.html">
        <img src="Logo.png" style="height: 80px;">
        <h1>&nbsp;-&nbsp;<spawn class="red">Zegmaar</spawn><spawn class="blue">Bas</spawn>.nl</h1>
    </a>
</div>
```

I want the first part of the text, "`&nbsp;-&nbsp;`" / "`-`" to **not** be underlined, like this:

[image]

I think [`text-decoration-skip: spaces;`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-decoration-skip/) would be the easiest way to accomplish this, however, almost no browsers support it (yet).

**How could I get the desired result?**

The more simple and elegant your solution, the better. I want to use only CSS and HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest option would be to use a custom class for this link

```
.headerLink {text-decoration:none;}
```

And then another class for the parts that should be underlined:

```
.headerLinkAction {text-decoration: underline;}
```

You may want to update the hover class as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can took off underline fom the anchor tag, then use underline to those part of word like this,

```
<div id="link-box" style="height: 80px; width: 335px;">
<a href="index.html" style="text-decoration:none;">
 <h1>&nbsp;-&nbsp;<spawn class="red">Zegmaar</spawn><spawn class="blue" style="text- 
 decoration: underline;">Bas</spawn>.nl</h1>
 </a>
 </div>
```

If you want to show the underline only on hover, then use class for hover with `text-decoration:none;`.

Comment: Doing it like this would give the underlines the same colour as the text, while I want them to be white, the same colour as the ".nl". Just as they are in the screenshots I provided.

Comment: Then also add text-decoration-color:white; which will show white underline.

Answer (score 0):

```html
Try this:
( Removed underline )

    <div id="link-box" style="height: 80px; width: 335px;">
        <img src="Logo.png" style="height: 80px;">
        <h1>&nbsp;-&nbsp;<a href="index.html"><spawn class="red">Zegmaar</spawn><spawn class="blue">Bas</spawn>.nl</a></h1>
    </div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work, because now the image, " - " and the space above and below the text won't be a link.

Comment: Add image inside of new <a href="></a> and will work. Not perfect but it work @Bassie-c